# Navigating through a fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment inside my main activity. I want to update the contents of the fragment dynamically a run time. Specifically, I want to populate the contents of fragment with new data on button back press. Please help me out in the same and suggest me how to achieve such a functionality.

```
//main_activity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_recyclerview"
                android:name="com.example.RecyclerViewFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout="@layout/fragment_recyclerview" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_dimen"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first fragment is the one that needs to be updated

Comment: Are you talking about [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Was thinking of doing something in onBackPressed() but then it is available in activity's context only

Comment: No not about FragmentTransaction. I just want my fragment contents to get updated on back press or button click or something. Just like we navigate through an activity(backstack does everything), I want the same for my fragment. The activity should remain intact but on an event the fragment should get repopulated with new data

Comment: Can you post your activity class and xml so I can head you to the right direction?

Comment: Post you fragment code and which data you want to update. what is inside your fragment? List? TextView or anything else that you want to update.

Comment: Well I have implemented fragment from xml file of main activity itself. So, the java file won't help. I've simply placed a fragment control in the layout file of main activity.

Comment: Fragment contains of recyclerview and I want to update that on back press or something like that

Comment: So you don't have yet your fragment inside a conatinerView in your activity?? If yes, you need first to solve that problem before attempting to update your fragment. I can guide you to some tutorials if that's the case

Comment: I have the fragment inside my mainactivity and its working fine. The only requirement is updating its contents-recyclerview. Let me attach the layout file of mainactivity

Comment: It would still be great if you guide me through thise tutorials that you brought forward in the last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//Find if fragment by tag 
        Fragment fr = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home");
        if (fr.isVisible()) {
        //do ur stuff

        } else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fr).commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Obtaining the reference of the contents of the fragment and updating them on back press worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I will give you an example of what I did in one of my projects...

My main activity xml contained a simple linear layout among other things:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_images_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity `OnCreate`, I added the following:

```
FragmentImages fragmentImages = new FragmentImages();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_images_fragment, fragmentImages).commit();
```

where `FragmentImages` is a class that extends `Fragment`

```
public class FragmentImages extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_images, container, false);
        //and here is where I wrote my codes for this fragment
        return v;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Ya, so you have implemented fragment through jav code. Now lets say I've a recycler view inside my fragment(in your case FragmentImages) and I wish to update contents of fragment on back press how should I proceed??

Comment: Add `public void onBackPressed() { }` to your activity not your fragment

Comment: I am overriding the same inside activity's implementation only

Comment: I didn't understand your last point. Did it help or is there still a problem I can help you with??

Comment: Well the problem is now solved. I updated the fragment contents by using references in the main activity and updated the fragment contents on back press.